# Is there a simple way to turn a data type deriving Enum into a list?

Tags: haskell, enums, algebraic-data-types

I have a snippet of code that looks something like this:

```
data SomeData = A | B | C | D | E deriving (Show, Enum)
```

and I want to be able to map certain values to these types easily. Say I wanted to have `char`s mapped to a `SomeData` type, I might do it like so:

```
mappings = zip "abcde" [A, B, C, D, E]
```

This would produce `[('a',A),('b',B)...]` and so on. I was hoping that the `Enum` type class might allow me to be able to do this easily by converting the data type into the list I described above (`[A, B, C, D, E]`) by use of some convenience function.

Is there such a function in the standard library? Or would I need to define it myself if I wanted to use something like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally, I'd do

```
mappings = zip "abcde" [A..]
```

but I'd be very tempted to go with

```
mappings = zip ['a' ..] [A ..]
```

so that if I added other letters later, the code would update.

Going with maximally future-proof work I'd define

```
import Data.Char

data SomeData = A | B | C | D | E deriving (Show, Enum, Bounded)

allData :: SomeData
allData = enumFrom minBound

mapppings = zip (map (toLower.head.show) allData) allData
```

where the only assumtion I'm making about the future is that it consists of single letters.

However, this is playing and not in fact all that clear.

Answer (score 7):

You can go even more generic:

```
-- added deriving Bounded
data SomeData = A | B | C | D | E deriving (Show, Enum, Bounded)

fullRange :: (Bounded a, Enum a) => [a]
fullRange = enumFromTo minBound maxBound
```

and then just call `fullRange` (with explicit type annotation if needed: `fullRange :: [SomeData]`).

Answer (score 5):

If you additionally derive `Bounded`, then you can even do this without explicitly knowing what the "smallest" constructor name is:

```
Prelude> data SomeData = A | B | C | D | E deriving (Show, Enum, Bounded)
Prelude> [minBound :: SomeData ..]
[A,B,C,D,E]
```

Answer (score 2):

If you take a look at http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/3.0.3.2/doc/html/GHC-Enum.html you can see that the function you need is a part of the `Enum` typeclass, if I understand your question correctly.

```
>enumFrom A
[A, B, C, D, E]
it :: [SomeData]
```

Comment: This is actually *exactly* what I was looking for. I came across it myself right after posting this. Thanks for the quick response!

Answer (score 2):

Actually, you could just use a range.

```
[A .. E]
```

As described in the invaluable [Learn You A Haskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com/making-our-own-types-and-typeclasses).

Answer (score 2):

Add `Bounded` to your deriving and you can do `[minBound ..]` to get a complete list.

Answer (score 1):

Try this in ghci

```
> [A ..]
[A,B,C,D,E]
```